# Using libcurl on visual c++ to login to a website, What can be considered a successful login?

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

When I try to use libcurl on visual c++ to login to a website, I find the example in the website https://www.hackthissite.org/articles/read/1078.
I running the instance, and the code as follows:

```
int main()
{

    curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
    CURL * myHandle = curl_easy_init ( );

    // Set up a couple initial paramaters that we will not need to mofiy later.
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1 );
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");

    // Visit the login page once to obtain a PHPSESSID cookie
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.hackthissite.org/user/login/");
    curl_easy_perform( myHandle );


    // Now, can actually login. First we forge the HTTP referer field, or HTS will deny the login
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.hackthissite.org/user/login/");
    // Next we tell LibCurl what HTTP POST data to submit
    char *data="username=myname&password=mypwd";
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
    curl_easy_perform( myHandle );
    curl_easy_cleanup( myHandle );

    return 0;
}
```

The above program running ok, but the console only output the html.
I don't konw the login is correct or not? 
What can be considered a successful login?
When I use the wrong password， the program also running ok without errors or bugs.

I find the above question through google and stackoverflow for many pages, but I can't find the correct result.
Please help me! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is very specific to the Website you are trying to log on. You Need to validate the HTML result from the Website.

Comment: I also want to make a small advertisement for my library tinyhtml++(https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyhtmlpp) which you can use for this :-)

Comment: ， Thanks for your reply，I download your library tinyhtml++, but I can't use it correctly. Do you have any Demo refer to me?

Comment: Yes, in the wiki there is a small example: https://sourceforge.net/p/tinyhtmlpp/wiki/Home/

Comment: Thank you, I already use your tinyhtml++. But the parse result is not what I want. I still don't know What can be considered a successful login?